# How to fix failing In-App purchase on production?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have already launched app with live users who have active in-app-purchases (subscriptions).

Recently I've added 2 new In-App Purchases (auto-renewable subscriptions) which duplicate existing 2 but with different price and everything got approved by Apple and released. But unfortunately none of these 4 in-app-purchases are purchasable now due to the following error:

> "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

But before that message box, I'm getting "You're all set" so that's kind 2 opposite messages at the same time. 
+ ALL existing subscriptions got affected as well - they aren't active and "Restore Purchase" option doesn't work... So my support chat is blowing up due to messages from existing users who have performed the purchase but got them deactivated. Purchase is still in the "Subscriptions" list in iPhone's settings.

I've tested all in-app purchases on Sandbox - works perfectly fine. All my Paid Apps agreements, banks, etc are OK - it was working just fine before I've added these 2 new subscriptions.
The release went live 24 hours ago.
All subscriptions are in "Approved" status and "Cleared for sale".

Did someone face the same issue? Is there any way to fix that?

For me it looks like the issue is on Apple's side: something got broken/stuck needs to be fixed because there is no code change on my side except these 2 new product ids.

Comment: Did you check this in production? Can you reproduce the problem? You have validation server, you recheck this server?

Comment: @Aisner yes, the issue is on production. Sandbox works fine. I’ve reverted 2 new subscriptions and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This error also had occurred when to SKProductsRequest passed wrong NSSet:

Wrong:

```
let products = NSSet(objects: ["id1", "id2"])
```

Correct:

```
let products = NSSet(objects: "id1", "id2")
```

So make sure if this is not the case! but anyway if this is the case it wouldn't be working on Sandbox also.

You can check this doc,
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-ACCTINFO

I'm sure you already have gone through this as well but still if help you,

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/98763

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately list of products is created without any issues, products even returns from Apple server successfully and the same code was working fine before. Sandbox also works fine.

Comment: I guess then you need to contact Apple guys to sort this out!